# Post not shown on custom post type Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I am using a template that has already the taxonomy Portfolio and the child "Skills" included. I wanted to create the Clients taxonomy so I replicate the function of Skills like this:

```
function thmlv_portfolio_register_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'skills',
        'portfolio',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Skills',
            'query_var' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'skills')
        )
    );
}

function thmlv_portfolio_register_taxonomy_client() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'client',
        'portfolio',
        array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'Clients',
            'query_var' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'client')
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'thmlv_portfolio_register');
add_action('init', 'thmlv_portfolio_register_taxonomy');
add_action('init', 'thmlv_portfolio_register_taxonomy_client');
```

Now in the Wordpress admin I can add clients perfectly to each project inside portfolio but when I go to the archive of that client I don't see any post. I don't see either a 404 page. I see a normal archive page without any post, just with the title of the client.

I tried to reset the permalinks few times and empty cache but still is not working. Any idea of why in the loop the SKILLS are working perfectly but not the CLIENTS? Am I missing anything? So Skills taxonomy loop is working perfectly but no clients loop when I go to the client/name-client page I only see the title of the section but no project at all. Of course I have added some projects to that taxonomy.

And this is in the Taxonomy.php file

```
<?php
/**
* The Template for taxonomy
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Tag
* @since Tag 1.0
*/
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy'));
get_header();
?>
<div id="thmlvContent">
    <?php echo tag_switch_header($post->ID); ?>
    <div id="ourwork" class="work-content">
    <?php
        include_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php'); 
        if(is_plugin_active('themelovin-portfolio/thmlv-portfolios.php')) {
            $args = array(
                'nopaging' => true,
                'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                'skills' => $term->slug,
                'orderby' => array('menu_order' => 'ASC', 'ID' => 'ASC')
            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
                get_template_part('loop-portfolio', get_post_format());
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
        }
    ?>
    <div class="thmlvClear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Firstly - if you want to be able to display them on an archive page - you should set `has_archive => true`. Secondly, what is the content of your `archive` page? It sounds like an issue with your query.

Comment: The thing is that the other one: skills is working perfectly without that. Added the taxonomy.php file

Comment: Solve I found the error. I have created a new file taxonomy-client with this: 'client' => $term->slug and now is working.